Recommended way to get snap apps to accept cursor theme
I installed a new cursor theme only to realize that it's not functional in snap apps. I found this discussion but am unsure as to what the recommended solution is. The theme I'm using is Bibata Modern Classic.

The post you link to only lists a single approach. So how can we advise on the recommended way?

@vanadium You mean https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-package-ignoring-cursor-theme/38810/6?
